# É possível verificar erro de uma função com um if()?

Tags: r, if

Estou usando o pacote `gtrends` para puxar uns dados do google.trends.

Esse pacote permite o download de 5 keywords por vez. Por isso, estou utilizando um `for()`

Entretanto, algumas keywords que preciso consultar não se encontram no período que eu procuro.

Quando a função `gtrends()` não encontra a palavra, ela da erro. Exemplos de keywords com erro: DDD, MMM.

Então, gostaria de saber: existe uma forma de criar um `if()`, para o caso de haver erro na função, ele alocar a keyword em uma lista e, se não, fazer o resto do procedimento?

```r
library(readr)
library(gtrendsR)


kwlist = readLines("keywords.csv")


resultslist <- list() 

for (keywords in kwlist){
  
  country=c('IT')
  time=("2018-08-01 2018-08-27")
  channel='web'
  trends = gtrends(keywords, gprop =channel,geo=country, time = time )
  resultslist[[keywords]] <- trends$interest_over_time
  
}
```

O erro, é esse:

> Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , timevar, value = "subject") :
> replacement has 1 row, data has 0

Me falaram que nas versões antigas do pacote, o erro não aparece. Mas fiquei curioso para saber é possível criar o if() para um erro.

Comment: Para capturar (e processar) erros há as funções `try` e `tryCatch`. Esta última é mais flexível. Pode dar um exemplo de palavras em que dê certo e outras em que dê erro? As suficientes para processar até ao fim, se possível.

Comment: Olá! Obrigado pela resposta! ` keywords <- c("FLWS","TXG","RETC","YSGG","EFSH","ONEM","ISOL","FNRC","TWGL","TWOU","TDCH","MRJT","DPSM","THDS","DDDX","MMM","FTPM","CATV","FFNT","SSOF","AOS")`  . Quando chega no MMM da erro. Depois, o próximo erro é em AOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O código seguinte lê o vetor de palavras-chave e cria duas listas, uma lista de resultados e uma lista de erros.

```
library(readr)
library(gtrendsR)

keywords <- c("FLWS","TXG","RETC","YSGG","EFSH","ONEM","ISOL",
              "FNRC","TWGL","TWOU","TDCH","MRJT","DPSM","THDS",
              "DDDX","MMM","FTPM","CATV","FFNT","SSOF","AOS")

resultslist <- vector("list", length = length(keywords))
errorslist <- vector("list", length = length(keywords))
names(resultslist) <- keywords
names(errorslist) <- keywords

country <- 'IT'
time <- "2018-08-01 2018-08-27"
channel <- 'web'

for(keyword in keywords){
  cat("Processando:", keyword, "\n")
  flush.console()
  trends <- tryCatch(gtrends(keyword, gprop = channel, geo = country, time = time),
                     warning = function(w) warning(w),
                     error = function(e) e
                    )
  if(inherits(trends, "error")){
    errorslist[[keyword]] <- trends
  } else {
    resultslist[[keyword]] <- trends$interest_over_time
  }
}

resultslist <- resultslist[!sapply(resultslist, is.null)]
errorslist <- errorslist[!sapply(errorslist, is.null)]

errorslist
#$MMM
#<simpleError in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , timevar, value = "subject"): replacement has 1 row, data has 0>
#
#$AOS
#<simpleError in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , timevar, value = "subject"): replacement has 1 row, data has 0>
```

Comment: Cara, valeu ! Se eu quiser salvar uma lista de kwlist que deram erro, ficaria `keyerrorslist[[KeyErrors]] <- keyword`?

Comment: @RxT Veja agora. Os nomes dos membros da lista são atribuídos antes do ciclo e se quiser pode fazer `errorslist$MMM`. Ainda, se não quiser ver o `"Processando: ..."` basta remover essas duas linhas (`cat` e `flush.console`), não têm importâncioa para o resto.

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado mesmo!